# EOFError in simple "Hello World" script

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

since a few days I've got the issue that my Visual Studio Code debugging does somehow not work. Even with the most simple script I'm getting errors.
I am clueless about the error cause.

Environment:

- OS: Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit

  - Linux Kernel: 4.15.0-38-generic
- Visual Studio Code: 1.28.2
- Python: 3.5.2

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# vim: set ts=4 sw=4 et sts=4 ai:

print("Hello World")
```

This is the output I get in the "python Debug Console" as soon as I press the debug arrow (F5):

```
cd /home/nsolthe/git/mass_deploy; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" python /home/nsolthe/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.9.2/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd_launcher.py 33739 /home/nsolthe/git/mass_deploy/test.py
Hello World
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nsolthe/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.9.2/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/wrapper.py", line 1292, in done
    fut.result()
  File "/home/nsolthe/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.9.2/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/futures.py", line 40, in result
    reraise(self._exc_info)
  File "/home/nsolthe/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.9.2/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/futures.py", line 149, in callback
    x = next(it)
  File "/home/nsolthe/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.9.2/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/wrapper.py", line 1527, in on_threads
    _, _, resp_args = yield self.pydevd_request(cmd, '')
  File "/home/nsolthe/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.9.2/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/wrapper.py", line 1317, in pydevd_request
    return self._pydevd_request(self.loop, cmd_id, args)
  File "/home/nsolthe/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.9.2/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/wrapper.py", line 435, in pydevd_request
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Anyone an idea why I get this errors?
Is there any more Information I can supply?

Regards

Comment: I would imagine the maintainers of ptvsd would monitor stack overflow.. But just in case - you might want to reference issue here too.. https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvsd/issues - if self.pipe_w is None: ... https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvsd/blob/master/ptvsd/wrapper.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I reported the issue I did many things to my system. but at the baseline I have updated all involved parts of the system to the newest version available to me.

- Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon 64-bit

  - Linux Kernel: 4.15.0-39-generic
- Visual Studio Code: 1.29.0
- Python: 3.6.6

Now these error messages don't come up anymore